How Do I Get Rid of the Natural Language Processing?
I'm using the free version of WolframCloud. I come back to it maybe two or three times a year, and it's nice (or was until they decided to lock everything I'd done more than 60 days old behind a paywall)
I've now come back to it after not touching it for about 4 months, and I suddenly can't use it. When I type in what should be perfectly good expressions in the Wolfram Language all I get is No Wolfram Language translation found.
Specifically, this is what I'm trying:
xformES = EigenSystem[{{1/2, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 1}}]

How do I switch the UI to let me enter Wolfram Language expressions again? Is this wonderful tool just gone now into the AI void?
Is it possible to get back the ability to type Wolfram Language expressions if I pay? I just want back what it was at the beginning of the year.

UPDATE: Even using a lowercase s as pointed out in comments doesn't help. My problem is that the UI insists on opening these orange boxes with an equal sign at the front, and I just want to type Wolfram Language input.
Screenshot:


Eigensystem is the function not EigenSystem

Even using a lowercase S doesn't help.
The problem is that I can't open up a "normal" input cell, only these damn natural language input ones. I just want a normal input cell.

It looks like that's a Wolfram Alpha notebook, not a normal notebook. You can't open normal notebooks from the File -> New menu?

@SjoerdSmit Ah! that's it. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Somehow I had accidentally created a WolframAlpha notebook, and creating a new normal Notebook got me back to sanity.
What a useless feature; why would anyone want Natural Language input with no way to turn it off for selected input cells? I can see that as the default, but in a normal notebook I can turn on NL mode by pressing an "=" sign up front; why isn't there a way to turn it off in a WolframAlpha notebook?

I assume the WA notebooks exist on the Cloud because there's a product called WolframAlpha Notebook Edition. I believe it's aimed at very low-technicality users. That's all I got.

It looks like that's a Wolfram Alpha notebook, not a normal notebook. You need to open a normal notebook using the File -> New menu.
On desktop you can convert a WA notebook to normal by changing the stylesheet under Format -> Stylesheet.
